# "Null" String to timestamp conversion in Talend

Tags: postgresql, null, timestamp, talend

I have timestamp column in excel which contains few "Null" values and the rest are timestamp values.

My target table for loading the data from excel to table has timestamp column also.

How to convert this "Null" to timestamp in Talend?

I am getting this error :

> Unparseable number: "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Just try with a quick search and replace NULL with 0 .

From what I can see from your error message, replacing null values with zero in the spreadsheet should solve the issue and allow it to be imported into postgreSQL .